# Is there a way to track transaction changes in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, database, transactions

In django, is there a way to find which rows were changed during a transaction?

There are CDC frameworks out there, however I would like to find the changes of a specific transaction with some sort of an ID. I would also want this to be synchronous with the rest of the runtime code.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try django debug toolbar. There are many option to track requests.

Pretty sure you will find something.

Comment: I should emphasise that the intention of the question is to get this data on the backend, not as a debug tool. Also, I need to know the changes themselves, not just the SQL queries.

Comment: Sorry. Does the save function return something useful?

Comment: I need to be able to track changes that were made with 'select_for_update'. Save / signals don't provide that.